# GORM with MemSQL json query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, singlestore

MemSQL has the ability to support JSON Query. Is GORM able to perform JSON query, or it is a must to write SQL in my application?

Comment: Given that a [plugin](https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions/blob/master/README.md) is required for JSON support on PostgreSQL I'd say you're stuck with SQL until someone writes a similar plugin for MemSQL.

Comment: Another option you have is to change your memsql schema to use JSON persisted columns. If this sounds workable, I can provide a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sqlType in the static mapping to match the MemSQL type 'JSON':

```
class Entity {
    String info

    static mapping = {
        info sqlType: 'JSON'
    }
}
```

Then you can push JSON data in doing something like this:

```
new Entity(info:'{"foo":"bar"}').save()
```